# Update amp-list data source without form

Tags: html, amp-html

I have an `amp-list` and I want to update its `src` dynamically without using `form`, just using a bunch of button `div`s that use data from `amp-state` that changes on tap on an element.

For example, tapping `#elementOne` will change `product.currentIndex` to `1`, so list's `[src]` will change to `'localhost/example/data?page=' + product.currentIndex` = `'localhost/example/data?page=1'`, hence the `amp-list` will be updated after `src` change.

Here's what I've tried so far:

```php
<amp-state id="product">
    <script type="application/json">
        {
            "page": 0
        }
    </script>
</amp-state>

<amp-state id="productState" 
           [src]="'localhost/example/data?page=' + product.page" 
           src="localhost/example/data?page=0"></amp-state>

<div role="button" tabindex="0" on="tap:AMP.setState({product: {page: 1 }})">
    <span>Page One</span>
</div>
<div role="button" tabindex="0" on="tap:AMP.setState({product: {page: 2 }})">
    <span>Page Two</span>
</div>

<amp-list width="auto" height="1024" layout="fixed-height" 
          src="localhost/example/data" [src]="productState.items">
    <template id="product-item-template">
        <!-- A template -->
    </template>
</amp-list>
```

Is there a way to do this without using form?

Comment: Do you mean: https://ampbyexample.com/components/amp-live-list/

Answer (score 3):

Just simply bind the src attribute of the `amp-list` to the calculated url string, like this:
`[src]="'/example/data/?page=' + product.page"`

Your markup should look like this:

```
<amp-list width="auto" height="1024" layout="fixed-height" 
      src="localhost/example/data" [src]="'/example/data/?page=' + product.page">
<template id="product-item-template">
    <!-- A template -->
</template></amp-list>
```